# How to hide the src in an imagebutton as you display loading animation

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

How can I temporarily remove this `src` in my `imageButton` as I play the loading animation, what I am doing currently is explicitly saying `visibility = gone`  which offcourse is throwing my button off proportion and just showing the loading spinner alone. Here is my xml. I also tried setting background to null, but this kind of removed the member_background drawable.

```
 <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/memberButton"
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
     android:background="@drawable/member_background"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_member_icon"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_one"
     app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


 <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
     android:id="@+id/animation_view"
     android:layout_width="30dp"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:elevation="3dp"
     android:scaleType="centerInside"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/memberButton"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/memberButton"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/memberButton"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/memberButton"
     app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
     app:lottie_loop="true"
     app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/white_spinner" />
```

Comment: One of the things that comes to my mind is, have another ImageView as an icon for ImageButton. Now you replace it very easily with all images even layouts by set images or making layouts visible or gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.memberButton);
image.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    LottieAnimationView animationView
            = findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
    animationView
            .addAnimatorUpdateListener(
                    (animation) -> {
                        // Do something.
                    });
    animationView
            .playAnimation();
    if (animationView.isAnimating()) {
        // Do something.
    }


   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            animationView.pauseAnimation();
            animationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 3000);
```